# In TortoiseGit, how do I "copy" certain files from a local branch?

Tags: tortoisegit

I am developing in the 'master' branch and want to copy some files from 'feature-1'. How can I do that with TortoiseGit?

(I am not interested in command-line solutions.)

Comment: Wrong tag?  You're question is about TortoiseSVN, but is tagged with tortoisegit.

Comment: Sorry I meant to ask about TortoiseGit. Fixed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. tortoisegit -> show log..
2. in the upper part of window, select the commit (click `all branches` if necessary) you want the file from
3. copy file(s) from revision to where?

   - into workdir: select the file(s) you want, right-click -> `revert to this revision`
   - single file anywhere: select single file, right-click -> `save revision to...`
   - many files (that are not same as in work dir) anywhere, with directories: right-click the commit, select `Compare with working copy`, select file(s), right-click, `export selection to...`"
   - everything in a single commit (as zip): right-click commit, select `export this version..`
   - ..or just use the command line, it's easier.

Comment: Step 3 should be "right-click the commit, select Compare with working copy, right-click, export selection to".

Comment: thanks @Borek - added that and one other way to save file from specific revision to some place.

Comment: Problem with selecting commit is that it will show you, well, only the files in that commit. I'd rather pick from a file tree as it was at that revision so the third option works best for me. Thanks.

Comment: And `compare with working copy` shows only the files that are different than what you have in work dir. I'll add two options...

Comment: "Save revision as..." is not listed in the right-click (properties) menu. I do see *Export this version...*. But that exports the whole checkin.

Comment: you saved the day MAN . JSVNM rocks.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add something. In my case I was looking for specific files located in different branches, so I had to add a `search text` in (1) and in (2) I selected `Branch`. Finally, for each file I selected `Revert to this revision` .

[image]